# Data in 1 column is getting stored in different row than other columns

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm Working on a swing project and i have a JDialogbox which contain two textfield and 1 combobox and two button "ok" and "cancel"and a Frame which have a text area which acts like Notepad and all of these Components are connected to Oracle Database whenever I insert data in JDialog and click on Ok the data is stored in database and the frame containing the text area is called and when i save the data written in textarea and click the save button the inserted Data is saved in different row in the Database but not in the same row as the JDialog components

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class newmenu implements ActionListener {

    JDialog jf;
    JButton okBtn,CanBtn;
    JTextField tf1,tf3;
    JComboBox type;
    JLabel prName,prType,prWritter;
    JFrame frame;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu file;
    JMenuItem open, save, exit;
    JFileChooser fileChooser;
    JTextArea textArea;


    public newmenu(){
        jf = new JDialog();
        jf.setTitle("New Report");
        okBtn = new JButton("Ok");

        okBtn.setBounds(10, 140, 60, 20);
        okBtn.addActionListener(this);
        CanBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        CanBtn.addActionListener(this);
        CanBtn.setBounds(100, 140, 100, 20);

        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(150, 20, 100, 20);

        String r_Type [] = {"Cosmetics","Pharametical","Medical"};
        type = new JComboBox(r_Type);
        type.setBounds(150, 60, 100, 20);

        tf3 = new JTextField();
        tf3.setBounds(150, 100, 100, 20);

        prName = new JLabel("Report Name");
        prName.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 20);

        prType = new JLabel("Report type");
        prType.setBounds(10,60,100,20);

        prWritter = new JLabel("Report Written");
        prWritter.setBounds(10,100,100,20);

        jf.add(okBtn);


        jf.add(CanBtn);
        jf.add(tf1);
        jf.add(type);
        jf.add(tf3);
        jf.add(prName);
        jf.add(prType);
        jf.add(prWritter);
        jf.setSize(300, 200);
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void notepad(){

            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setTitle("Notepad");
            file = new JMenu("File");

            save = new JMenuItem("Save");
            save.addActionListener(this);
            exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            exit.addActionListener(this);
            textArea = new JTextArea();
            fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            menuBar = new JMenuBar();

            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.add(textArea);

            file.add(save);
            file.add(exit);
            menuBar.add(file);
            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);



            frame.setSize(800, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    public void insert(){
         try {

                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","root");
                Statement st = con.createStatement();

                st.executeUpdate("insert into report (reportname, reporttype,clientname) VALUES('"
                        + tf1.getText() + "','" 
                        + tf3.getText() + "','" + type.getSelectedItem()+ "')");





            }

            catch (Exception e1)

            {
                System.out.println("Exception:" + e1);
            }
}

    public void notepadinsert(){
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","root");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            st.executeUpdate("insert into report (report) VALUES('"
                    + textArea.getText() + "')");





        }

        catch (Exception e1)

        {
            System.out.println("Exception:" + e1);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){

        if(ev.getSource()==okBtn){
              if( tf1.getText().trim().equals("")){

                    okBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    if(tf1.getText().hashCode() != 0){
                        okBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    }
          else{
              okBtn.setEnabled(true);
             jf.dispose();
             insert();
               notepad();
          }

        }

        else if(ev.getSource()==CanBtn){
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else if(ev.getSource()==save){
            notepadinsert();
        }
        else if(ev.getSource()==exit){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }






    public static void main(String args[]){
        new newmenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: For that you have to save all the data at once not in pieces

Comment: Can You Please Explain it by customizing my code.

Comment: Use update command instead referring to same ID.

Comment: Actually i don't have DB installed and my system is quite old... SO i can just tell you how to do it... It won't be that i can check it...

Comment: DO this have different action listeners and call notepad() method before inserting the data... And then get the data from notepad back and call insert method and pass the values that you want to insert... It will be in one row only...

Comment: Exception:java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword        I tried the update command

Comment: @CoderNeji I'm kind of a Newbie in Java It'll be Really helpful if you Explain it to me with the code.

Comment: Just give me some time... i will get back to you... For sure

Comment: @CoderNeji Thank You!

Comment: See my code... I just changed your action performed and insert method.. Hoping it will help you...

Comment: If my answer helped you accept it so that people searching for this can be helped

Comment: Yes!It Helped me.Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag to check if it's a first request.

```
private int flag=0;
...
insert(){
...
    if(flag==0){  
    //insert command 
    flag=1;
     }
   else
    {
       //update here.
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
A better way can be to check if the current user has done the update..You have to create a field (like user_name) because I cannot see that in your insert query .

```
insert(){
...

    //search for the current record with user_name in DB
    if(!found){  
    //insert command 
     }
   else
    {
       //update here.
    }

}
```

Comment: flag is the most offensive way in coding, why don't we resolve the main problem instead of twisting the code by using flags?

Comment: @STaefi Agreed . Updated.

Comment: thanks for openness in mind. Proud to have people like you in community.

Comment: @STaefi That was really a overwhelming  comment thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Chnged your code like this... In the `insert()` method now you have data to be stored... Store that data in database in one go... I have added `System.out.println();` because i couldn't create an oracle database and this was only way to check if i am getting all the data needed...

You just write your code for inserting into the DataBase in the insert method and pass the values from the string array which i have used to print the values...

```
    public void insert(String[] Str){  // Write your code for insertion
                                       // of values in database
        System.out.println(Str[0]);     
        System.out.println(Str[1]);    // I just used these to check
        System.out.println(Str[2]);    // If i am getting correct values
        System.out.println(Str[3]);            
      }   

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){    

        String[] Data_To_Insert = new String[4];    

        if(ev.getSource()==okBtn){
              if( tf1.getText().trim().equals("")){    
                    okBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    if(tf1.getText().hashCode() != 0){
                        okBtn.setEnabled(true);
                      }
                    }
          else{
              okBtn.setEnabled(true);                 
              jf.dispose();             
              notepad();
            }    
         }    
        else if(ev.getSource()==CanBtn){
            System.exit(0);
          }    
        else if(ev.getSource()==save){
            Data_To_Insert[0] = tf1.getText();
            Data_To_Insert[1] = tf3.getText();
            Data_To_Insert[2] = type.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Data_To_Insert[3] = textArea.getText();
            insert(Data_To_Insert);
            }
        else if(ev.getSource()==exit){
            System.exit(0);
          }
       }
```

Also remember you have to create 4 columns to store the data...

Hoping it helped...